# Disable liferay control panel for ALL users?

Tags: liferay, admin

Is it possible to disable liferay control panel for all users, including admninistrator's? If so how can it be done?

Comment: And after it was disabled for admninistrator, how can you manage the portal?

Comment: Just revoke admin permissions. And please see [help/on-topic]